# WCF error serializing cycle reference

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, entity-framework

I'm trying to return lists of objects that have references to another objects and viceversa.

I only want the lazy load to get the "first level children", I mean, if I have a "Person" object with a "Place" property, I want the place data to be loaded but not every object in "Place" object needs to be loaded... because this would ahead to a cyclic reference...

I've read that I could do this by using [DataContract(IsReference = true)] on every Object.

I've set every object in the model (auto-generated by EF) with that decoration but it's still failing when trying to send it back to the service caller.

Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean, if I have a "Person" object
>   with a "Place" property, I want the
>   place data to be loaded but not every
>   object in "Place" object needs to be
>   loaded...

That is not possible when using lazy loading. Once the entity gets serialized the serializer will access every single property. Accessing every navigation property will trigger lazy loading and serializer will continue with loaded properties => it will always serialize complete object graph. In your scenario it can mean:

1. Serializer will start with a `Person` which have navigation property to `Place`
2. Lazy loading will load the `Place` and serializer will serialize.
3. If the `Place` have navigation property to all `Persons` lazy loading will trigger and load all persons referencing the `Place`!
4. Serializer will start serializing every single loaded `Person` - if `IsReference` is set to `false` you will get exception with cycles in object graph. If not it will create huge message.

That is very basic explanation what happens if you try to serialize object when using lazy loading. If your entities have other navigation properties the same effect will happen for them. In the worst case you can easily build an operation which will try to pull and serialize all data from the database. That will most probably lead to timeout.

There is one more problem with lazy loading. Serialization takes place outside of operation scope. So if you close / dispose `ObjectContext` in the operation you will get an exception when entity triggers lazy loading.

Don't use lazy loading when exposing entities on WCF or use DTO to control what data should be passed from the operation.

Comment: this is all true.  If you don't want lazy loading to load all of your instances all the way down, then you could replace the `Place` instance with a `PlaceProxy` which implements the same interface but only has soem properties initialized and the others are no ops.  Doesn't address the OPs question of why the cycles are still occuring (assuming that really is her issue).  You should be prefereably be returning DTOs from the service though.  Then the issue goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought I understand the problem but it's far mor clear now. I think I'll create my own model (almost the same than my EF model) with only some properties for each object and load it before returning it. Do you mean this with DTO's?? Or should I build a different class for every case I'll find?? Thanks!!

Comment: Yes I mean that by the model. Creating different class for every case is also possible but it introduces a lot of work. It is usually used in big projects or when optimizing amount of transfered data.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. I wanted to avoid this because I have a huge data and I thought Microsoft would have give any solution ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I have used the `[DataContract(IsReference=true)]` successfully to solve the cyclic dependency issue in the past.  Admittedly they were not objects generated by EF, but I' not sure how much that should matter.

What is the exact error?

Is it that the graph is getting to big?

Could it be that your objects are not the same instances, but different instances of the conceptually same type?

So when your TypeA-instance1 gets serialized and it has a reference to TypeB-instance1 which has a Reference to TypeA-instance1 the 2 actual TypeA-instance1 objects to not compare equal so the serializer does not attempt to reuse the references?

You could override the equals method on your objects and do some equality testing based on properties of your object rather than the default memory address that will be used.

Comment: Uhmmm this sounds interesting. My service just crashes when it tries to return the value, not cyclic references or anything I can understand... I'll take a look at this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: have you enabled logging?  That might tell you what the issue is, or at least let you see the exception that is happening.

Comment: After a long google searh about this issue I must say that [DataContract(IsReference=true)] attribute in my DTO classes worked out for me!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to convert your object tree to other, flat objects and return those instead.

Comment: I've think about this option but I have a huge data model and it's a lot of work I thought I could avoid ;-). Thanks for your answer, I'll mark it as correct if I fynally solve it with this.